# Trying to get linksys wifi dongle to work wusb600n version 1

Tags: wireless

Trying to get my wifi usb dongle to work on Ubuntu 17.04 it is a linksys wusb600n version 1. Shows wifi networks. However, it does not connect and the indicator light on the dongle does not turn on. Once you plug it in, the indicator light blinks a few times then shuts off. Need a driver that I can install on my system to make it work. No drivers from linksys or support either. PLEASE HELP! Been at it for two days now. Any command line read outs you need, I can provide. Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lsusb`

Answer (score 1):

You may have better luck connecting if you make a small change to Network Manager. Open a terminal and run:

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

At the bottom of this file, copy and paste the following:

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

Proofread carefully, save (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and close (Ctrl+x) the text editor. Restart Network Manager:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Any improvement?

Comment: 55 you are amazing! That fixed it! My frustration is now gone. Keep up the good work with helping everyone. I would kiss you right fnow. :)

Comment: If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour  Glad it's working!